# Format Preserving Encryption (FPE) in Java with Bouncycastle

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, encryption-symmetric

[Release notes](https://www.bouncycastle.org/releasenotes.html) for Bouncycastle release: 1.69 (7 June 2021) state:

> An implementation of the two FPE algorithms, FF1 and FF3-1 in SP 800-38G has been added to the lightweight API and the JCE provider.

These can be found in `bcprov-jdk15on` JAR.

Here is the code that tries to use it:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AlphabetMapper;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.BasicAlphabetMapper;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.spec.FPEParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@Slf4j
public class AesFpe {

    @Test
    public void testAesFpe() throws Exception {
        SecretKey key = generateKey();
        byte[] tweak = getTweak();
        int radix = getRadix("0123456789");
        Charset encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        byte[] plaintext = "510123456".getBytes(encoding);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/FF3-1/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(cipher, key, tweak, radix, plaintext);
        log.info("Ciphertext: {}", new String(ciphertext));
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(cipher, key, tweak, radix, ciphertext);
        assertThat(decrypted, equalTo(plaintext));
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(Cipher cipher, SecretKey key, byte[] tweak, int radix, byte[] plaintext) throws Exception {
        AlgorithmParameterSpec fpeParameterSpec = new FPEParameterSpec(radix, tweak);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, fpeParameterSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(Cipher cipher, SecretKey key, byte[] tweak, int radix, byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {
        AlgorithmParameterSpec fpeParameterSpec = new FPEParameterSpec(radix, tweak);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, fpeParameterSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
    }

    private SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        int keyLength = 256;
        keyGenerator.init(keyLength);
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }

    private byte[] getTweak() {
        int tweakLength = 7;
        byte[] tweak = new byte[tweakLength];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(tweak);
        return tweak;
    }

    private int getRadix(String alphabet) {
        AlphabetMapper alphabetMapper = new BasicAlphabetMapper(alphabet);
        int radix = alphabetMapper.getRadix();
        log.info("Radix: {}", radix);
        return radix;
    }
}
```

I haven't come across an example how to use it correctly. The problem seems to be with radix. Execution of the above results with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input data outside of radix
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.checkData(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.checkArgs(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.encryptFF3_1(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.FPEFF3_1Engine.encryptBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.FPEEngine.processBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedFPEBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2164)
```

With radix set to e.g. 64 or higher this code works, but this is no longer a FPE - ciphertext contains characters outside of [0-9] scope. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle may not support the original FF3, but NIST has published examples with an 8 byte tweak using radix 10, and 256 bit key:

*Sample #11
 from
[FF3samples.pdf](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/FF3samples.pdf)



FF3-AES256

Key is EF 43 59 D8 D5 80 AA 4F 7F 03 6D 6F 04 FC 6A 94 2B 7E 15 16 28

AE D2 A6 AB F7 15 88 09 CF 4F 3C

Radix = 10

Tweak is D8 E7 92 0A FA 33 0A 73

Plain Text is 890121234567890000

Cipher Text is 922011205562777495*

FF3-1 is still a draft and there are no published test [examples](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/example-values).

The test class [SP80038GTest.java](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/test/SP80038GTest.java) seems unfinished for FF3-1. They have all nine NIST test cases for FF1 in *ff1Samples[]*, but only 1 for FF3-1 with a 256 bit key in *ff3_1Samples[]*. You may consider switching to BouncyCastles's FF1 to have proper test coverage or using my [Mysto FF3 & FF3-1](https://github.com/mysto/java-fpe) implementation.

Here is the one test example in BouncyCastle FF3-1 with radix 10, 7-byte and a 256 bit key:

```
private FFSample(int radix, byte[] key, byte[] plaintext, byte[] ciphertext, byte[] tweak)
    {
        ...
    } 

FFSample.from(10, "1A58964B681384806A5A7639915ED0BE837C9C50C150AFD8F73445C0438CACF3", "4752683571", "2234571788", "CE3EBD69454984")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try my code .
I can run this test case successful

```
@Test
public void testAesFpe() throws Exception {
    SecretKey key = generateKey();
    byte[] tweak = getTweak();
    AlphabetMapper alphabetMapper = new BasicAlphabetMapper("0123456789");
    int radix = alphabetMapper.getRadix();
    char[] plaintext = "510123456".toCharArray();

    byte[] plain_bytes = alphabetMapper.convertToIndexes(plaintext);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/FF1/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider());
    byte[] cipher_bytes = encrypt(cipher, key, tweak, radix, plain_bytes);

    byte[] decrypted = decrypt(cipher, key, tweak, radix, cipher_bytes);
    char[] cipher_chars = alphabetMapper.convertToChars(cipher_bytes);
    System.out.println(new String(cipher_chars));

    char[] plain_chars = alphabetMapper.convertToChars(decrypted);
    System.out.println(new String(plain_chars));
}
```

Comment: How do I provide the format to preserve? For instance, harshicorp says **(\d{2})-(\d{2})-\d{4}**.  this format would preserve the date format, encrypt the day and month bits but keep the year unencrypted