# Reason for the error: "input too short", when encrypting (with FPE and bouncy castle) in Java/Scala

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

Based on the answers of [this another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226233/format-preserving-encryption-fpe-in-java-with-bouncycastle), I am trying to encrypt some text but when the input data is 3 characters or less in lenght, I obtain this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input too short
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.checkLength(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.checkData(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.checkArgs(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.SP80038G.encryptFF1(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.FPEFF1Engine.encryptBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fpe.FPEEngine.processBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedFPEBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
at org.example.AESFPE2.encrypt(AESFPE2.scala:38)
at org.example.AESFPE2.encrypt_test(AESFPE2.scala:25)
at org.example.App$.main(Main.scala:18)
at org.example.App.main(Main.scala)
```

The method 'encrypt_test' in the next code is what I am using to test this problem (the rest of the methods are the same as the previously referenced question):

```
class AESFPE2 {
 @throws[Exception]
 def encrypt_test(): Unit = {
   val key = getKeyFromPassword("foo", "bar")
   val tweak = getTweak
   val alphabetMapper = new BasicAlphabetMapper("\"'^*[]{}<>ºª|+-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzáéíóúü!¿?¡=()/\\ _;:,.ç")
   val radix = alphabetMapper.getRadix

   val plaintext = "abc".toCharArray

   val plain_bytes = alphabetMapper.convertToIndexes(plaintext)
   val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/FF1/NoPadding", new BouncyCastleProvider())
   val cipher_bytes = encrypt(cipher, key, tweak, radix, plain_bytes)
   val decrypted = decrypt(cipher, key, tweak, radix, cipher_bytes)
   val cipher_chars = alphabetMapper.convertToChars(cipher_bytes)
   println(new String(cipher_chars))
   val plain_chars = alphabetMapper.convertToChars(decrypted)
   println(new String(plain_chars))

 }

 @throws[NoSuchAlgorithmException]
 @throws[InvalidKeySpecException]
 def getKeyFromPassword(password: String, salt: String): SecretKey = {
   val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
   val spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray, salt.getBytes, 65536, 256)
   val secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded, "AES")
   secret
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the specification ([here, page 13, line 504 ff](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-38Gr1-draft.pdf)), the following must be fulfilled to FF1:

> *radix* ∈ [2..2<sup>16</sup>]
> *radix<sup>minlen</sup>* ≥ 1 000 000
> 2 ≤ *minlen* ≤ *maxlen* < 2<sup>32</sup>

Here, *radix* is the number of characters in the alphabet (99 in the sample code) and *minlen* and *maxlen* are the minimum and maximum allowed length of the plaintext.

The constraint *radix<sup>minlen</sup>* ≥ 1 000 000 is fulfilled for *minlen* = 4, but no more for *minlen* = 3, i.e. the minimum length of the plaintext is 4 characters.

The error message comes from [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/fpe/SP80038G.java#L451).